# How to find encoded html value in chrome?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, google-chrome, xss, html-encode

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#html-encoding-using-razor)

> The Razor engine used in MVC automatically encodes all output sourced
> from variables
> So for the following razor view

```
@{
    var untrustedInput = "<\"123\">";
}

@untrustedInput
```

This view should output the contents of the `untrustedInput` variable. This variable includes some characters which are used in XSS attacks, namely <, " and >.

So my expectation was browser source code will show the encoded value as:
`&lt;&quot;123&quot;&gt;`

But instead I see the rendered value
[image]

Where would I actually see the encoded value in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found it. I am looking at the wrong tab.
If i open Network->my route->Response Tab. I see the encoded value